# Quadro 4000 and gtx 645 same machine

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

I am merging two computers one has a quadro 4000 and the other is a gtx 645. I have heard that the gtx is better for gaming, the quadro better for moddeling, of witch i like to do both. I was wondering if I could have them both running on the same machine, or at least have them both installed and flip a setting on the computer depending on what task i am working on.

Os: Windows 10
Please tell me if I forgot anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Nvidia Control Panel you can set what application is using what graphics board.

Anyway, this is not valid for all applications, some of them will attempt to search for GPU's on their own and use the GPU they decide to use.

In the end it all depends on the application you are using, it is not at all a matter of installed boards.

Quadro boards have a lot of professional features unlocked compared to gaming cards, so again it just depends on the software you target. For example, i need to use 20 concurrent H264 video encodings in paralell, then i can only use the quadro because the GTX is locked to 2 paralell streams.

Additionally, depending on the usecase, you can only use some features when there is no display connected to the board.

Again and after all, it all depends on your software. Please edit your question if you have more requirements to add.